# why "thus was"? is it correct gramatically?

Tags: grammar

in a sentence, I saw "thus was" and I wonder if its grammar is corretct or not?

Thus was the basis created for a strong presidential system

Comment: Yes, it is correct. What causes you to doubt it?  (*Thus* can be substituted with *In this way*)

Comment: Why the sentence is not this: "thus the basis was created for a strong presidential system"

Answer (score 4):

The sentence  *Thus was the basis created for a strong presidential system* is grammatical. It uses a syntactic feature called *inversion* to reverse the standard SV (subject-verb) order in declarative statements. By fronting *thus* and inverting the normal word order, the writer is giving special emphasis to the *thus* and linking it more strongly to the analysis or examples given in the preceding sentences.

Here is an entry about inversion after *thus* in *The Right Word at the Right Time* (p631):

> *Thus* is occasionally followed by inverted word order, as in *Thus did
>   we triumph*. ... Such inversion is clearly old-fashioned, though it can
>   - as here - be used to good effect.

Comment: To add to Shoe's answer, the original (uninverted) sentence would be _The basis was thus created ..._.